# How do I make an Angular JS controller work alongside a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

I'm learning Angular JS. I've written (OK, found and reused) two basic functions:

- controller: a basic show/hide toggle
- directive: a 'back to top link' which appears when you scroll
  100 pixels

The snippets both work individually. For some reason, when I try to combine them into one module called 'scrollApp' one of them stops working.

html:

```
<div ng-app="scrollApp" scroll id="page" ng-class="{min:boolChangeClass}">

<div class="static-button"><a href="#"> Back to top</a></div>

<button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
<p ng-show="myVar">
this is the content to hide
</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
         if (this.pageYOffset >= 100) {
             scope.boolChangeClass = true;
         } else {
             scope.boolChangeClass = false;
         }
        scope.$apply();
    });
};
});
```

I've been learning Angular code from tutorials but now I'm trying to write up SPAs with multiple functions. Any advice would be welcome. Thanks!

Codepen version:

http://codepen.io/angeltapes/pen/embGJw/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind the controller to your app with `ng-controller="personCtrl"`:

```
<div ng-controller="personCtrl" ng-app="scrollApp" scroll id="page" ng-class="{min:boolChangeClass}" >
```

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEMzdW

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object instead of the link function on the directive factory. One of the attributes of this object is a controller. You can specify the controller of the directive as an string (The controller name) or a function. There is the controllerAs attribute that you use to access the controller inside the template.

```
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
return {
  controller: 'personCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
         if (this.pageYOffset >= 100) {
             scope.boolChangeClass = true;
         } else {
             scope.boolChangeClass = false;
         }
        scope.$apply();
    });
}  
};
```

http://codepen.io/Raulucco/pen/RNELeM?editors=101